# How to calculate sum for specific property without grouping main list data

Tags: c#, linq, group-by, sum

I'm fetching Invoices from database and I want to return all invoices without grouping them!

I don't want to group them since If there are 100 invoices I want to return all of them 100, considering that I want to get Sum of Amount.

So it is perfectly fine to repeat same Total for multiple invoices if their sum is the same, so basically ***I want to calculate sum of Amount of each invoice item and group by CompanyId, PackageId, BankId, PayMethod*** only if it's possible?

*-- Read code comments --*

```
var result = await _dbContext.Invoices
                       .Where(p => p.CheckDate >= startDate && p.CheckDate <= endDate)
                       .Select(p => new DemoDto()
                       {
                           CompanyId = p.CompanyId,
                           Title = p.Title,
                           Price = p.Price
                           Total = p.Sum(p => p.Amount).ToString(), // Can I sum here and group by fields I mentioned above? without grouping all data set because I want to keep all 100 records if I received all 100 from database
                       })
                       .ToListAsync();
```

This query obliviously doesn't work because it says

> Invoice does not contain definition for Sum and no accessible method..

DemoDto looks like this:

```
public class DemoDto
{
  public string CompanyId {get;set;}
  public string Title {get;set;}
  public decimal Price {get;set;}
  public decimal Amount {get;set;}
}
```

Invoice class looks like this:

```
public class Invoice
{
    public string CompanyId { get; set; }
    public int PackageId {get; set;}
    public int BankId {get;set;}
    public int PayMethod {get;set;}
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public decimal Amount { get; set; }
}
```

what I'm missing here?

How can I achieve this?

Thanks guys
Cheers

Comment: How does this statement _I don't want to group them_ exist with this _I want to calculate sum of Amount of each invoice item and group by CompanyId, PackageId, BankId, PayMethod_?

Comment: There is no reason to store in every entity the sum of all the entities

Comment: You can group by and fetch the same list after grouping by calculating the sum for the Total column.like this approch : ``productPrices.GroupBy(p => p.ProductId)
 .SelectMany(x => x.Select(y => 
  new ProductPrices 
  { 
   ProductId = y.ProductId, 
   VendorId = y.VendorId, 
   Price = y.Price, 
   Total = x.Sum(z => z.Price) 
  }))``

Comment: @Sajid Can you apply your solution in my code I'm wondering how can I modify my code to apply this what you wrote? Thanks a lot Sajid!

Comment: @Roxy'Pro, i can apply it, so for you case, we will group by *CompanyId, PackageId, BankId, PayMethod*?

Comment: @Sajid That is true, how that could look ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Fetch all the invoices from the database:

   ```
   var invoices = await _dbContext.Invoices
                    .Where(p => p.CheckDate >= startDate && p.CheckDate <= endDate)
                    .ToListAsync();
   ```
2. Group the in-memory results using Linq-To-Object:

   ```
   var result = invoices?
                    .GroupBy(p => new { p.CompanyId, p.PackageId, p.BankId, p.PayMethod })
                    .SelectMany(x => x.Select(y =>
                        new DemoDto
                        {
                            CompanyId = y.CompanyId,
                            Title = y.Title,
                            Price = y.Price,
                            Total = x.Sum(z => z.Price)
                        }))
                    .ToList();
   ```

If you want to perform the grouping in the database for some reason, you should execute a raw SQL query or a stored procedure rather than relying on the ORM to generate some magic (and most probably inefficient) query for you.